# debian python2.6 as default?

Tags: debian, python

is it possible to set the default python to 2.6 for debian lenny somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd just like to comment on [Dennis Williamson's answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/64624/debian-python2-6-as-default/64637#64637):

Using the command line provided for the "install" commands results in this error:

```
update-alternatives: error: alternative link is not absolute as it should be:
                            python2.5
```

it looks like the syntax to create the alternative would rather be:

```
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python python /usr/bin/python2.5 1
```

Ie, the first parameter needs to be an absolute path, not just a name.

Answer (score 5):

If alternatives are already set up:

```
update-alternatives --config python
```

then choose from the list that's presented.

If they're not set up, then do this:

- If there is a symlink already set up, save it:

  `sudo mv /usr/bin/python /usr/bin/pythonSAVE`
- create the alternatives

  `sudo update-alternatives --install python2.6 python /usr/bin/python2.6 2`

  `sudo update-alternatives --install python2.5 python /usr/bin/python2.5 1`
- create a new symlink

  `sudo ln -s  /etc/alternatives/python /usr/bin/python`
- choose the one you want to use

  `sudo update-alternatives --config python`

Comment: Why wouldn't the alternatives be setup?

Comment: I don't know. On my system, even though other programs were already set up, python wasn't  despite the fact that I've got 2.5, 2.6 and 3.0 installed.

Comment: I can say now that aptitude checks to ensure that python is a symlink to /usr/bin/python2.6.  This bypasses the alternatives system.  Perhaps that need for debian_default python, plus the availability virtualenv and buildout, are why python is not configured with alternatives.

Comment: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/python-support/+bug/224438